# What should Main (F&N) FAQ say about health/medicine questions & answers?

Tags: discussion

The [FAQ](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) is not specific about the extent to which medical-advice questions are appropriate at [Fitness & Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/).  The FAQ *does* prohibit vague or unanswerable questions, overly local (personal) questions, and subjective/argumentative questions; as such, there are criteria to close some medical questions.  *A well-formed question of general interest that nonetheless requires some form of medical decision-making could be problematic.*

A [recent question here on meta](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/medical-questions/132) raised the possibility of new close criteria - so this is NOT a question about new close criteria.  Rather, **I'm asking how the FAQ should be amended** (another user here [suggested asking this question](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/medical-questions/132#132)).

Comment: I totally agree we need to avoid these questions as much as possible.

Comment: @IvoFlipse: it's not really possible to avoid the questions being asked, though. I'm curious what the reaction should be. I have flagged one, but that's going to get old fast. So I am now just commenting on the question, asking to rephrase.

Comment: @djangodude With that comment I meant rather that we shouldn't be endorsing or actively encouraging them. Comments are always good, even if you flag them for our attention as well

Comment: OK, thanks...sounds like I'm doing the right thing, then! :-)

Comment: FYI there is a [health SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2) that is in commitment phase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wikipedia Reference Desks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk) have a [prohibition against requests for medical advice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Guidelines/Medical_advice), and a [user there has proposed a criterion for identifying such questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aKainaw/Kainaw%27s_criterion):

> Can the question be answered completely without providing a diagnosis, prognosis, or treatment advice?

This might be a useful starting point for the FAQ.

Comment: Just to be explicit: I am not wikipedia user "Kainaw" - I just read about this on Wikipedia and thought it was useful.

Comment: This is excellent. This quote should be included in the "not about" section of the faq. See this faq as an example: http://superuser.com/faq "If you have a question about … **and it's not about … "**